# Cannot find antMatchers when using spring-boot-starter-security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to configure the security policy for spring security. I need some routes to be protected and some to be public. But for test purposes I only have one route called "secure" which needs to be authenticated.

But I am getting this error:

```
No candidates found for method call http .sessionManagement() .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) .and() .authorizeRequests() .antMatchers("/secure/**").
```

For ant matchers in my SecurityConfig:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/secure/**").authenticated() // Cannot resolve method 'antMatchers' in 'ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry'
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

I am using `spring-boot-starter-security` version `3.0.2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`authorizeRequests()` is deprecated and `.antMatchers()` has been removed. Use `.authorizeHttpRequests()` and `.requestMatchers()` instead.

```java
.authorizeHttpRequests()
.requestMatchers("/secure/**").authenticated()
// ...
```